# How to make mini media player in notification area in Firefox OS?

Tags: firefox, web-applications, firefox-os

Tried to read how it works in Gaia Music player, but didn't succeed to port it to my app, while no errors happened.
Also I didn't found any relevant information about this, Gaia project uses a lot of undocumented things which sometimes are not obvious at all.

So, I need simple widget in notification area with title, artist, cover and prev/play-pause/next buttons. Just like in default music app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the widget is [hardcoded](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/apps/system/js/media_playback.js) in the system application.

A patch is [in the works](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=965105) to let others create widgets on the lockscreen but it has not been landed yet, and doesn't seem to land anytime soon.

Comment: I saw that widget, and that Gaia Music player interacts with it, but I didn't succeed to copy that interaction into my application.

Comment: Well, you can't, unless you're certified app; as it relies on sending chrome events through gecko.